# How can I join two tables that should be only one in a query without using auxiliary tables? (left join using two columns would work)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to work with a model that is not perfect, since two different tables should be only one... let's simplify the model and show it:

```
Table: Survey
Columns: ID_SURVEY | SURVEY_TYPE | SURVEY_QUESTIONS

Table: SurveySent
Columns: ID_SENT | ID_USER | ID_SURVEY | TMST_SENT

Table: SurveyAnswered
Columns: ID_RECEIVED | ID_USER | ID_SURVEY | TMST_RECEIVED | ANSWERS

-- the first column is the primary key, columns wiht same name are foreign keys
```

Now if I'd built the model SurveyAnswered and SurveySent would have been the same table since a survey answered only exists if first a survey was sent, or at least make survey answered dependent on a survey sent.

However this cannot be the case, so I'm trying to get the results with a single query, hopefully and efficient one, since I cannot write anything.

What I'm trying to get is the number of surveys a user has received, the number of surveys this user has answered, all this for one specefic type of survey. After a lot of tries, the only way I managed to do this is by a joining two subqueries:

```
SELECT Z.ID_USER, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_SENT), COUNT(DISTINCT ID_RECEIVED) FROM
  (SELECT A1.ID_USER, A1.ID_SENT 
    FROM SurveySent A1 
    JOIN Survey B ON A1.ID_SURVEY = B.ID_SURVEY 
   WHERE B.SURVEY_TYPE = @MyType) AS Z
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT A2.ID_USER, A2.ID_RECEIVED 
    FROM SurveyAnswered A2 
    JOIN Survey B ON A2.ID_SURVEY = B.ID_SURVEY 
   WHERE B.SURVEY_TYPE = @MyType) AS Y
ON Z.ID_USER = Y.ID_USER
GROUP BY Z.ID_USER
```

Is there a way to do this with a single query (not one with 2 subqueries)? It seems the heart of the problem is I want to join on two columns simultaneously: ID_SURVEY and ID_USER But I haven't found a way to do this in a single query...

Things like:

```
SELECT A1.ID_USER, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_SENT), COUNT(DISTINCT ID_RECEIVED)
FROM SurveySent A1
LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswered A2 ON A1.ID_USER=A2.ID_USER
JOIN Survey B ON B.ID_SURVEy = A1.ID_SURVEY
WHERE B.SURVEY_TYPE = @MyType
 AND (A2.ID_SURVEY = B.ID_SURVEY OR A2 IS NULL)
GROUP BY A1.ID_USER
```

Don't work because the nulls are lost after the left join... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `survey` table to "drive" the query.  That is, make it the first table and use `left outer join`s.

```
SELECT s.ID_USER, COUNT(DISTINCT ss.ID_SENT), COUNT(DISTINCT sa.ID_RECEIVED)
FROM Survey s left outer join
     SurveySent ss
     on s.id_survey = ss.id_survey left outer join
     SurveyAnswered sa
     on s.id_survey = sa.id_survey and ss.id_user = sa.id_user
WHERE B.SURVEY_TYPE = @MyType;
```

Comment: Almost, but the results are not fully coherent... I'll keep working on this see if I can get somewhere.

Comment: My fault, the real problem adds more complexeity, but I got it, thanx a bunch... I changed a few things and at the end of the day the "outer" where unnecessary... the missing link for me was to use "Survey" to drive the query and the trick to join on two conditions which I didn't know you could do.